# Sliding up view in android. without including that view in every layout

Tags: android, view, slidingdrawer

I need to show a view sliding up for all my pages(fragments). Just like navigation drawer working. I don't want to include layout in every view and animate. Please suggest a solution

Comment: You need it like a vertical viewpager or something .Question is so small. Could you please explain more then We can help you more??

Comment: you can do it easily using [PropertyAnimation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#views)

Answer (score 0):

Create a common base class that your fragments extend from. What is the purpose of the sliding view? Does is just animate a scroll within a fixed space? Does it move above it up when it animates in? Does it overlay over the view as it slides up? Need more clarification.

Comment: I'd suggest using the comments when asking for clarifications to the OP, not a new answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [AndroidSlidingUpLibrary](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel).

I'd avoid using it for scrolling views, it is nice though.